# trim string to first space python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe of this style:

```
id                      patient_full_name
7805                  TOMAS FRANCONI
7810                  Camila Gualtieri
7821                  Lola Borrego
7823                  XIMENA ALVAREZ LANUS
7824                  MONICA VIVIANA RODRIGUEZ DE MARENGO
```

I need to save the first name of values from the second column. I want to trim that value down to the first spacing and I don't know how.

I would like it to stay in a structure like this:

```
patients_names = ["TOMAS","CAMILA","LOLA","XIMANA","MONICA",...."N-NAME"]
```

All this done in Pandas Python

Comment: `s = 'TOMAS FRANCONI'` then `s.split()[0] 'TOMAS'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function in a list comprehension to do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 7805, "patient_full_name": "TOMAS FRANCONI"},
    {"id": 7810, "patient_full_name": "Camila Gualtieri"},
    {"id": 7821, "patient_full_name": "Lola Borrego"}
])

df["first_name"] = [n.split(" ")[0] for n in df["patient_full_name"]]
```

That adds a column (`first_name`) with the output you wanted, which you can then pull off as a list or series if you want:

```
first_name_as_series = df["first_name"]
first_name_as_list = list(df["first_name"])
```

In your question, you show the desired output in all upper case. That's easy to get with a simple tweak to the list comprehension:

```
df["first_name"] = [n.split(" ")[0].upper() for n in df["patient_full_name"]]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is giving me the following error: "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using extract as well, which do not rely on a loop:

```
(df
 .assign(first_name=lambda x: x.fullname.str.extract(r"(.*) "))
)
```